# Eclipse RCP user friendly GUI components

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, eclipse-rcp

I am going to develop a Java application using Eclipse RCP, In fact I am new with this framework. My main problem is about this two issues:

- If RCP plugins (if I am right) supports RTL UI and Languages?
- Is there any set of UI components to be able to use them in desktop application? such as ribons and so on which exists for other languages like C#

I have searched a lot but could not find any good sources to answer these questions, 
Thanks very much

Comment: To see which widgets SWT supports, see here: https://www.eclipse.org/swt/widgets/ and for Nebula (a collection of custom SWT widgets) here: https://www.eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/gallery/gallery.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Eclipse RCP gets the same set of controls that Eclipse itself uses (since Eclipse is just an example of an Eclipse RCP). These are the SWT and Jface controls plus things Eclipse builds on top of those controls.

SWT support RTL, LTR, and mixed directions. Eclipse RCPs and plugins can support multiple languages with different directions (including different icons for each langauge).

For Eclipse e4 style RCPs you can also use JavaFX.

Comment: thanks very much, is JavaFX for desktop development? Also do you suggest me to head to JavaFX or SWT?which one is more powerful ?

Comment: JavaFX is for desktops. I don't use it. Most Eclipse tutorials will assume SWT

Comment: Thanks very much, I am really concerned about the GUI I have no idea if I can find a set of good looking and modern UI pack for it